# error: package org.apache.cordova does not exist (Using PhoneGap/Cordova)

Tags: android, cordova, mobile

G'day!

I'm trying to develop a Cordova application. It's not the first time. It's too strange, but last week I developed an app with no problems, and this week I can't even develop a "Hello world". Nothing changed (no system variables, nothing was installed, nothing different was done).

I'm trying (I use elementary OS/Ubuntu):

```
$ cordova test/ com.WhiteDev.test Test
$ cd test/
$ cordova platform add android
```

Then importing the "test/platforms/android/" folder in Android Studio. It imports correctly (AFAIK), but in time to compile, that's what I have:

```
Error:(23, 1) error: package org.apache.cordova does not exist
```

And so on:

```
Error:(25, 35) error: cannot find symbol class CordovaActivity
Error:(30, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable super
Error:(31, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable super
Error:(33, 17) error: cannot find symbol variable launchUrl
Error:(27, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 35.801 secs
Information:7 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Just a detail: I did not put any code into the project, yet. At the time of the compile test above, the code in the app was the default Cordova test (the one that tests the onDeviceReady event).

What I've tried:

- Downloading Android SDK separated, uncompressing and putting its path into my PATH variable
- Run "cordova build" and "cordova build android" in the project folder. It says "BUILD SUCCESSFUL", btw.

But no luck. It seems that Cordova is not being included into the project.

Has someone faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For me installing the latest Android SDK (API 22) solved the same problem!